# One-line code in bashrc to edit pdf

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, bash-alias

I would like to have a one-line code in bashrc, for removing the first page of a pdf. The command to be typed in the bash prompt could of the form:

> cut name.pdf

This command should remove the first page of name.pdf and save the file under the same name. How should I do this? I have alias commands in bashrc and pdftk package, but I do not know how to use them together to this end.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which distro you are using, but if you are running debian (or derivates), you can use the following (if package qpdf is installed);

```
qpdfcmd() { qpdf ${1} --pages ${1} 2-z -- /tmp/temp.pdf && mv /tmp/temp.pdf ${1}; }
alias cut='qpdfcmd'
```

note: quick and dirty solution, this is not usable in a multi-user environment, nor does it make use of secure temporary file names.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked and answered many places, but [this looks the most complete](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3378/modifying-pdf-files) that my search-fu could find today.